# Displaying debug outputs into MacOS terminal

Tags: macos, debugging, terminal, qt-creator, error-logging

On Mac OS X the debug outputs go to the system logger that can be read with the Console Application. But when you are developing outside of Xcode (using QtCreator or just the terminal for example), it's not very practical to check the system logs for debugging.

Is there any way to force MacOS to print the backtrace to the terminal (similar to Linux behavior) without any trick on the application side ??

I'm developing a new feature for Clang so it's a C++ program. And I'm using MacOS 10.13.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using qt, then include QDebug and then use qDebug() as follows:

```
qDebug() << debug_qstring;
```

And if you are using XCode and ObjC, look for NSLog.

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...);
```

Also printf in case of C and std::out in case of cpp are always your friends!

Comment: That's what I was meaning by application tricks. There is no way to configure MacOS to print the backtrace into the shell without modifying the application?

Comment: Can you tell me what is your platform and library you are using exactly? And also the language?

Comment: I'm developing a new feature for Clang so it's C++.
I'm using MacOS 10.13.3

Comment: And also how are you writing the output backtrace?

Comment: I haven't changed anything so it's done there:
http://llvm.org/doxygen/PrettyStackTrace_8cpp_source.html

Comment: Ok, so you should see what OS stream is. Then maybe you can redirect it to std::out without changing the code.

Comment: Found it, defined here: 
http://llvm.org/doxygen/PrettyStackTrace_8cpp_source.html#l00105
So it's going to stderr, but also to __crashreporter_info__
But stderr should not be displayed to the shell ?

Comment: Redirrct it to see if the problem gets solved! Std::err should be visible in the terminal, but it depends on the way you run your process.

Comment: No, it is not working... The full backtrace i'm looking for is not in stderr but I can find it in the system logs... I don't understand :(

Comment: This means what you are looking for is not there. Search for a common part of the log you are seeing.